# Как сконвертировать VTT и другие форматы в текстовый формат?

Tags: java, android

```java
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    Log.e("Async=doInBackground", "1" + "");
    connection= (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

    VttParser parser = new VttParser("UTF-8");
    VttObject subtitle = parser.parse(
                         new FileInputStream("file:///android_asset/test.vtt"));

    Log.e("Async=doInBackground", subtitle.getCues().size() + "");
    Log.e("Async=doInBackground", subtitle.getCues().get(0).getStartTime() + "");
} catch (IOException | SubtitleParsingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
return null;
```

`VttObject parser.parse` принимает `InputStream`. Но из интернета он его почему то получает пустым.

Вся проблема в том что при считывании потока нужно создавать `OutputStream`.
А `VttObject` принимает только `InputStream`

> Выдает такую ошибку  fr.noop.subtitle.model.SubtitleParsingException:
> Unexpected line: WEBVTT

https://github.com/noophq/subtitle вот библиотека

---

Я попробовал использовать локально из `assets` все заработало. И что получается мне тогда делать? создавать файл внутри Android. Считать данные из `InputSteam` и после добавить данные в файл. А после Считать из файла `VttObject`?

Как по производительности сильно ли это упадет?

Comment: Автор, хватит удалять свои вопросы. Люди тратят время на редактирование, а вы удаляете.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Ну а что мне делать.
Темы новые создавать не могу потому что старые не закрыты. Не закрыты потому что ни кто не отвечает. А к тому времени я уже сам на кодил вручную свой парсер.

Comment: `Темы новые создавать не могу потому что старые не закрыты` – нет, не по этой причине. Тут нет лимита на количество одновременно заданных вопросов. Наоборот, удаление — это одна из причин,  почему может быть заблокирована возможность задавать новые вопросы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, А этот сервис отличается от английского? там нельзя создавать темы если старые не закрыты